# Bootstrap4, images and borders

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to figure this one out: I have a modal window with a body like this:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
    <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_1"></div>                    
    <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_3"></div>                    
    <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_5"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_6"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_7"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_8"></div>
</div>
```

JS switches exactly one of the elements to be bigger which means I replace it with either a `col-sm-3` (now the borders collide right side of the green img):

[image]

or a `col-sm-4` - which means it is not center-aligned any more:

[image]

The green image has the following CSS attributes:

```
background-size: cover;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
border: 2px solid yellow;
outline: 2px solid white;
```

Small image has the same class, but `width = 64px; height = 48px`.

I know the outline is not "pushing" the other image (which also has a outline right now) to the right - but how would I achieve that? I want let's say 4px between every `<div>` (or image inside the `<div>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<style>
    .sel {
        background-size: cover;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        outline: 2px solid white;
    }
</style>


<div class="col-6">

    <div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/64x48/000/fff" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 mt-auto sel" id="sec_2"><img class="mx-auto d-block" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000/cacaca" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_3"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/64x48/000/fff" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_4"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/64x48/000/fff" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_5"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/64x48/000/fff" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_6"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/64x48/000/fff" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_7"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/64x48/000/fff" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 mt-auto" id="sec_8"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/64x48/000/fff" alt=""></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Explanation**

Important: I have simulated the case of the class added by JS through the SEL class.

I have added the "mx-auto d-block" class to image on this cell, that centers the image inside the div inside of all the space available.
You can see the example in the following [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/images/).

good luck!